# expected expression before '.' token

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
-(IBAction) website_btn {
    [myAppDelegate viewGallery];
}
```

Because I am getting this error.

> error: expected expression before '.' token

I know it sounds strange.  Need someone to throw me a life jacket here.

Comment: There’s nothing visibly wrong in the code snippet you’ve posted. Are you sure the error refers to that?

Comment: Agree with Bavarious...There is no any error in this code...Are you sure that the error refers to this code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!!!!

It was an error I had causing this error.

Just remember to extend your class with UIApplicationDelegate.

```
...

@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate> {

....
```

Sorry, I am new to iPhone so I know I am not using proper terms here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling with GCC in Xcode, try switching to clang, clang is much better at identifying where there error is, GCC will sometime claim an error is at one location when the actually error is much higher up or even in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted has no issues. It may be due to the error in the code above it. If still the code is fine. Then clean all your target and Build again hope this will work. As it works for many of us..

Comment: Thanks for down voting... But if you are downvoting some one's answer then you should also comment on that e.g. (-1) : Reason for downvoting